# Grouping arrays in to cells

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, grouping

Is there an efficient way to perform this example?

```
values = randn(100,1);
classes = randi(20,100,1);
for ii = 1:numel(unique(classes))
    C{ii} = values(classes == ii);
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If order within each cell is not important: you can use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) that returns a cell:

```
C = accumarray(classes, values, [], @(x) {x}).';
```

Comment: Nice one. Using the anonymous function to convert it to a cell array is a good one... +1

Comment: @kkuilla Yes, it was quite a revelation when I found out `accumarray` can return cells!

Comment: I didn't know about it. Another one... What does the dot do before the transpose (`'`)? Are you applying `transpose` element-wise?

Comment: @kkuilla That notation with the dot is confusing, but `.'` means simply "transpose". The commonly-used `'` is not transpose; it is _conjugate_ transpose. I like to use plain transpose for clarity, even if the numbers are real

Comment: @kkuilla Hahaha. No, it's been there for several weeks now. Suggested by Divakar (if memory serves), because I said it's one of my Matlab pet peeves